# ¿Es necesario poner un atributo href a una etiqueta a?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy usando una etiqueta **a** pero con un **onclick** y no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o en realidad la forma correcta es usando un **href** sin que lo necesite.

Comment: Realmente, depende del contexto para el que se vaya a utilizar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hola sólo se debe utilizar la etiqueta anchor  para navegación utilizando una URL adecuada, frecuentemente se hace abuso de estas etiquetas con el uso de eventos onclick para crear pseudo-botones ajustando href="#".

Estos valores pueden llegar a provocar comportamientos inesperados.

Te recomendaría que en su lugar utilices la etiqueta `<button>`.

Si querés más información sobre este tema, te dejo este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a) de Mozilla.

Answer (score 17):

Si revisas la especificación [justo aquí](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) notarás como:

Un elemento que sea de tipo `a` tiene la posibilidad de incluir un atributo de tipo `href` el cual sirve para enlazar a una URL como recurso externo que ha de ser consumido al dar click sobre el texto que coloques entre la apertura y cierre de dicha etiqueta; mas o menos así:

```
<a href="algunsitio.com">Ir a algún sitio</a>
```

Entonces no es tanto que sea incorrecto lo que haces de darle una acción en el evento `click` sino que *esta demás ya que si incluimos dicho atributo obtenemos la misma funcionalidad*

Considera que si vas a usar dicho evento, sería mas conveniente o lógico para situaciones en las que por ejemplo tratas de manipular la *data* que se ingresa a un `input` y por ende realizarás una o varias acciones en concencuencia.

En específico si nos fijamos en dicho [estándar](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) podrás leer y cito:

> El atributo `href` en elementos `a` y `area` no es requerido, cuando esos elementos no tienen el atributo `href` no crean hipervínculos.

Entonces a la pregunta, no no es necesario, pero usar JS para dar dicho efecto es agregar considero yo complejidad extra que con un simple atributo que existe de forma nativa vas a poder conseguir.